# Can I draw conclusions from sources?

Tags: essay

When you write an essay or something like that, and you're referencing to a source, are you allowed to "draw conclusions" out of the source.

Example:
If the question I'm gonna answer is "What was XX called before 2002?"
The source says: "Today (in 2002) YY in New York changes it name to XX"

Am I allowed to write "XX was called YY before 2002"? I mean, the source just says that the YY in New York changed name, not every YY, but I could draw the conclusion that XX was called YY before, not only in New York. Or do I have to part it into to sentences like "In 2002 YY in New York became XX instead (Source, 2002). Thus, XX was called YY before."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can draw conclusions but they should be supported by your sources.

None of your examples satisfy the statement above.

Consider the following sentence

> From tomorrow the first day of the week in New York is no longer called Monday but Firstday.

Could you take such a conclusion?

> The first day of the week is called Monday everywhere in the world.

Probably not, in light of the fact that most of the world uses non-English names for the days of the week. Also, the week starts on different days depending on where you are.

Make sure your sources support precisely the conclusions you want to draw. If you cannot find a good argument to present a general statement, restrict your statements to the premises of your sources. It is better to sound pedantic but precise, than concise but imprecise. Regardless of whether they are central to your discussion, any poor argument in an essay, or any attempt at forcing conclusions from sources that do not support them, is going to shed a negative light on the quality of the remainder of your text.